# datagridview.columns.add vs datagridview.columns.insert?

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows

while using windows applications coding in c# i noticed something confusing, 
`datagridview.columns.add` vs `datagridview.columns.insert` ?

could it be used interchangeably ? or at a time ? what is purpose of each ?

```
 DataGridViewColumn dtCol = new DataGridViewColumn();
 dtCol.Name = "ID_New";
 dtCol.DataPropertyName = "ID";
 dtCol.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
 //dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dtCol);
 // dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
 dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(3, dtCol);
```

Answer (score 3):

`DataGridViewColumnCollection.Insert` Method

Inserts a column at the given index in the collection.

```
DataGridViewColumnCollection.Add Method
```

Adds the given column to the collection

Answer (score 0):

[datagridview.Columns.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.insert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Inserts a column at the given index in the collection.

```
private void CreateUnboundButtonColumn()
{
    // Initialize the button column.
    DataGridViewButtonColumn buttonColumn =
        new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
    buttonColumn.Name = "Details";
    buttonColumn.HeaderText = "Details";
    buttonColumn.Text = "View Details";

    // Use the Text property for the button text for all cells rather 
    // than using each cell's value as the text for its own button.
    buttonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

    // Add the button column to the control.
    dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, buttonColumn);
}
```

[datagridview.Columns.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc3sctb6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Adds the given column to the collection.

```
private DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

private void AddColorColumn()
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboBoxColumn =
        new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    comboBoxColumn.Items.AddRange(
        Color.Red, Color.Yellow, Color.Green, Color.Blue);
    comboBoxColumn.ValueType = typeof(Color);
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboBoxColumn);
    dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing +=
        new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(
        dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing);
}

private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (combo != null)
    {
        // Remove an existing event-handler, if present, to avoid  
        // adding multiple handlers when the editing control is reused.
        combo.SelectedIndexChanged -=
            new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);

        // Add the event handler. 
        combo.SelectedIndexChanged +=
            new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }
}

private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((ComboBox)sender).BackColor = (Color)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
}
```

Comment: @JohnNash Sorry I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `DataGridViewColumnCollection.Insert` Method

it will inserts a column at that index in the collection.
and when you use `DataGridViewColumnCollection.Add` Method 
it will add the given column to the collection in the last.

for Example : if you have 4 columns

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(3, dtCol);
```

will replace column 3 with new dtCol and still you will have 4 columns

if you use

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add (dtCol);
```

will add new column new dtCol and  you will have 5 columns